# Is there a defined operator or notation for a row by row scalar product of column vector and matrix?

Tags: tensor-products

Is there a defined operator or notation for a row by row scalar product of column vector and matrix?

For example if
$$
\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ \  A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & 
 c\\ d & e & f \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then using this operator product would be
$$
\vec{x} \odot A = \begin{pmatrix} 2a & 2b & 2c\\ 3d & 3e & 3f \end{pmatrix}
$$

Note that this is equivalent to Hadamard product if $x$ was repeated to match the columns of $A$:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \vec{x} & \vec{x} & \vec{x} \end{pmatrix}  \circ A $$

I tried using the outer product of vectors as well as the it's generalization the Kronecker product, but I couldn't seem to replicate the exact behavior.

Thanks in advance,

Also not sure how to properly tag this, so I'm going to leave this with the tag of Tensor Products.

Comment: If you're willing to define $\operatorname{diag}(x)=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&&\\&x_2&\\&&\ddots\end{bmatrix}$, then this is $\operatorname{diag}(x)A$.

Comment: That option might be the best available if no such specific notation exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new tensor $\delta_{ijk}$ such that

$$\delta_{ijk}=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if}\;i=j=k\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

where $i$, $j$ and $k$ range over the number of rows of your matrix. Then in the summation convention:

$$(\vec x\odot A)_{il}=\delta_{ijk}x_jA_{kl}$$